# How much a tablespace for index on the same disk influences the performance?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

If I created a tablespace for indexes at PostgreSQL 9.5 on Ubuntu 16 installed on a virtual machine and separated them away from the tables but still on the same disk, will it be effective in enhancing the performance or not ?

Comment: I only see two reasons to use tablespaces in Postgres: 1) you can't extend your current filesystem 2) you want to distribute I/O load (but then a RAID might be a better choice)

Answer (score 2):

Postgres's tablespaces are directories only. When they share same disk, then they has zero impact on performance. Compare with Oracle, the Postgres's tablespaces don't help with performance (when they share the same physical device). Compare with Oracle, with Postgres there are not too many reasons to use tablespaces.